# Spring boot JPA DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes, named **Product** and **ComboProduct**. Product contains all the information about a particular product and has a Primary Key `productId`. ComboProduct holds a list with a `@OneToMany` relationship to the Product and has a primary key named `comboProductId`. When I create multiple `Comboproduct` instances with the same set of products, I get the following `DataIntegrityViolationException`:

```
  

      public class Product {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long productId;
        @OneToOne
        private MasterProduct masterProduct;
        @NotBlank
        private String productName;
        private String productDescription;
        
        private Double productSellingPrice; // mrp
        private Double productOfferPrice;   // price at which the user sells
        private Double productPurchasePrice;
        private float totalTaxPercentage;
        
        private float productMargin;
        
        @OneToOne
        private MerchantStore store;
        
        
        @ManyToOne 
        private ComboProduct comboProduct;       @Entity
        public class ComboProduct {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long comboProductId;
        private String comboProductKey;
        @OneToMany
        private List<Product> products;
        @NotBlank
        private String comboName;
        private String comboDescription;
    
   
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; 
constraint [UK_nm4dyaqp2f780nx73vq9abbw3]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
could not execute statement\n\t
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:298)\n\t
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)\n\t
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:538)\n\t
at org.springframework.transaction.support.


How can I resolve this?
```

Comment: Please format your code better (especially the stack trace) and provide your sql schema for the two classes in general and minimum reproducible code like how you are populating the classes and persisting them.

Comment: @SumitGarg you have a constraint violation exception. Most likely your entities have some other entities as a relation, and you don't persist them.. or some field isn't persisted but is mandatory.

Comment: How many repositories do you have ? One per Entity ? Or only one for ComboProduct ? How do you use those repositories ? Can you provide the code where you call the repositories ?

Comment: One per Entity. Yes One for ComboProduct.   public DealResponseDto addNewDeal(CreateDealRequestDto dealReqDto) {
          ComboProduct cp = new ComboProduct ();
       cp.setStore(dealReqDto.getStoreId()));
        cp.setProductCategory( dealReqDto.getCategory()));
              comboProductRepo.save(cp);
             }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have modeled a One-to-Many relationship, you defined that one combo is associated to multiple products. But products can only be assigned to one combo.

If you want products to be able to belong to multiple combos, you would need to model a Many-to-Many relationship. That would of course also imply to have a respective mapping table on the database.

Comment: Yes, I have done that as well. refer the revised code above. same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Relationships between the 2 entity classes were not established properly.
`

```
@Entity 
public class Product {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue    (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long productId;

@ManyToOne 
private ComboProduct comboProduct; }


@Entity 
public class ComboProduct {     
@Id     
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long comboProductId;      
@OneToMany     
private List<Product> products; 
} `
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to tell Hibernate that the `OneToMany` mapping will use a foreign key on another table, otherwise, it will assume that the entity in the list must have a unique Id.

To do so, you must add `@JoinColumn` on the attribute owning the mapping (class `ComboProduct` attribute `products`).
Try the following:

```
@Entity
public class ComboProduct {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comboProduct")
    private List<Product> products;
```

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;
    private String productDescription;
    private Double productSellingPrice;
    private Double productOfferPrice;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ComboProduct comboProduct;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and have revised the code above, still the same issue.

Comment: you need to define the owner of the relation ship, because you have a `OneToMany` and a `ManyToOne`. So who is the owner for you ? But I'll update my example for you